# Upgrading Acer 1760 PSU - not ATX

Tags: power-supply, gpu, adapter

I have just bought a new graphics card that needs more power than the standard 300W PSU supplied with my Acer Aspire TC1760.  So went out, watched a video, bought the recommended PSU, and now, the cables dont connect.

The photo shows that the existing PSU has 2 cables, 1x4pin and 1x6 pin, both go directly into motherboar.  Both circled in red.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bPd6e.jpg)

I have bought an EV3A 600W PSU, which comes with everything i need for graphics card, but, also comes with a 20+4 power adapter. I have tried every combination of plugging pins into boxes, to no avail.  Can anyone recommend a solution, I've seen a few 20+4 adapters, but not sure what exactly I need to fit to on this motherboard?

Comment: can you find a manual for your MB; one such normally has the info you need.

Answer (score 0):

Your model needs a compatible TFX ATX12VO PSU.  Other voltages are generated by the MB's [voltage regulator modules](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voltage_regulator_module).

It's a budget PC that was well rated in all areas except GPU upgradability based on the PSU's output & rarefied nature. See review: [Acer Aspire TC Desktop](https://www.reviewed.com/laptops/content/acer-aspire-tc-desktop-review)

A PC can't be all things, and this system was designed to be reasonably priced and maximize performance and power efficiency in a small form factor while also minimizing manufacturing costs and complexity.

You could scrap the existing setup to get some hardware that is more flexible for future upgrades but, assuming you are committed to upgrading your existing PSU, you are best to work with Acer's parts department to identify a PSU that would be compatible with your case and components.

Comment: Thanks, in the end I just found a newer microATX motherboard and rebuilt the pc.  Much better now and gone from 32gb to 64gb.

Felt it was better to lay out £150 for a more future proof setup,.plus the m.2 on old board was only pcei x3 whereas new one has 4 lanes, so getting more from
M.2 ssd

Comment: Makes sense, my answer was based on upgrading the existing PSU.  I'll improve my answer.  If I answered your question please accept and/or upvote so others with the same problem are more likely to find it.  See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)